# remote connection to mysql

Tags: mysql, windows, c#, remote

have two machine PC#1 with db mysql and appache and PC#2 with a c# form try to connect to this db

here is my connection string used in PC#2: `SERVER=My_public_ip;PORT=3306;DATABASE = my_test; UID = root; PASSWORD = xxxx;"`

when i try to connect locally from PC#1 it work good:

```
SERVER=localhost;DATABASE = my_test; UID = root; PASSWORD = xxxx;"
```

i did make my root user remote enabled like that:

```
`GRANT ALL ON *.* to '%'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
```

and all i get is an Event viewer: unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL host

now i think it has nothing to do with firewall aftr turn them off on both pc and i still get the same error message, but i can't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the root user with a password

```
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH 'rootpass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I would make it a little more secure. Perhaps by doing the following:

- use a username other than `root` (like `remote_user`)
- instead of `%`, user the netblock of the IP of PC2 (such as `10.20.30.%`)

Therefore, you run this grant command  on PC1 instead

```
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
GRANT ALL ON *.* to remote_user@'10.20.30.%' IDENTIFIED WITH 'rootpass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Note : `SET sql_log_bin = 0;` prevents recording the GRANT into the binary logs.

## Give it a Try !!!

In your question, you said you ran this

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to '%'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Wildcard characters are not allowed for the user. In fact, the [MySQL Documentation on GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) says

> MySQL does not support wildcards in user names. To refer to an anonymous user, specify an account with an empty user name with the GRANT statement:

Your grant should say

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

or

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to remote_user@'10.20.30.%' IDENTIFIED WITH 'rootpass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: but i am already have a password to the root user its in my connection string instead of xxxx,  and i did GRANT all privileges